# Fancybox 2 with dynamic json content

Tags: jquery, json, fancybox

I'm trying to add some dynamic content to a Fancybox 2.0 popup when somebody clicks a button. I tried several things but I can't get this to work. I always get a "The requested content cannot be loaded." error.

I first want to load the json content when a button is clicked and then open the popup with the content...

**UPDATED QUESTION SINCE IT WAS DUPLICATED**

What I have:

HTML

```
<a href="#quick_cart" class="opener cart" id="productid_1234" data-fancybox-href=" url-to-product">Add to cart</a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          $('.opener').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).data('fancybox-href') + '/?format=json';
            console.log(url);

            $.fancybox({
              type: 'inline',
              beforeLoad: function (){
                quick_cart(url);
              }
            });
          });
        });
        function quick_cart(url){

          $.getJSON(url, function (data){

            $('#quick_cart').append('<div>' + data.product.title + '</div>');

          });    
        }
```

The script loads the right url for the json content and fills the hidden div #quick_cart. The problem however is that I get an error "The requested content cannot be loaded." I can't figure out why...

Can it be that "type: inline" isn't right? I tried several things and even deleted that line but no luck. When I delete that line the popup doesn't show up.

What I'm I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a list of issues. Will start with some. 1). in `var url = $(this).attr("href")+'/?format=json';`, `$(this)` should refer to a selector because at this point is `undefined`. 2). You are missing to show the html of the element where you want to get the `href` attribute from, as in number [1] 3). `$(this).fancybox()` only binds fancybox to `$(this)` but it doesn't trigger it. You may rather do `$.fancybox()` instead. 4). You have an extra trailing comma at the end of your API options **AND** an extra loose closing `}` curly bracket in your code (you'll see a syntax error)

Comment: @JFK: Ok thanks for the heads up! But overall the "setup" is the right way to do it?

Comment: Still don't see where do you get the `href` value from in `$(this).attr("href")+'/?format=json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after literally pulled out all my hair on this one. So to help somebody else here's the solution:

The code doesn't know where to put the HTML generated in the function quick_cart.
Therefore a simple href attribute to the fancybox code is enough. Like so:

```
$.fancybox({
   type: 'inline',
   beforeLoad: function (){
     quick_cart(url);
   },
   href: 'quick_cart'
 });
```

Hope this may help somebody ;)